# Box.com OAuth - Increasing Expiry Time For App User

Tags: oauth-2.0, box

I'm hoping if someone with Box OAuth experience might be able to answer my question about creating an Application User for Box.com. This is different from the Box Integration but the Box Platform (creating a user itself that can login to your Box supported app).

See here: [Box - Authentication Types & Security](https://docs.box.com/docs/authentication-types-and-security)

I'm not having any issues going thru the process of creating the Enterprise Token or the App User Token, however it seems the maximum expiry time of this token is limited to ~60 minutes or so.

```
body:
   { access_token: 'XXXXXXX',
     expires_in: 3817,
     restricted_to: [],
     token_type: 'bearer' } }
```

If I try to adjust the expiry (exp) time within the claims of the JWT Assertion any higher I receive a:

```
  body:
  { error: 'invalid_grant',
    error_description: 'Please check the \'exp\' claim.' } }
```

My question is if this expiry can be adjusted at all? Or is this limited to an hour of expiry time?

Thanks!
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expiration time for both the Enterprise Token and the App User Token cannot be changed. The expiration time is set to one hour.